# Is there a way to add an element to the same height as another selected element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am new to front-end development. I was trying to code an annotation tool. A sample screen is shown on the image below. After the user select a sentence, an annotation box appears on the right side bar at the same horizontal position as the highlighted sentence. Any ideas about how I can achieve that effect?

[image]

Here is my html structure. I used the framework of Zurb Foundation:

```
  <section id="main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-8 large-8 columns"id="rawdata">

                <p> <span class="sentence">2:22 So, last time I was here, I don't know if I told you this, but, um, we kind of did a "I like, I wish" activity on paper, about things that you like about studio, and things that you wish would change.</span><span class="sentence"> Um, do you want to share any of those thoughts now, so maybe we can talk about them? [name], I have yours if you want to look at it again.</span></p>
                <p><span class="sentence">2:47 I forgot to add something.</span></p>
                <p><span class="sentence">2:54 Well, I don't know, in terms of what I dislike about studio.</span></p>
                <p><span class="sentence">2:57 So, some people wrote in theirs that, um, they dislike how cluttered it gets.</span></p>

                <p><span class="sentence">5:09 I don't get bothered.</span>< <span class="sentence">I like the draftiness, I'm a little...</span><span class="sentence"> I'm one of the ones that opens the windows, and like—</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-4 large-4 columns" id="annotations"><p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

JS for selecting sentence and adding annotations:

```
 <script>
        $('.sentence').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('sentenceStyle');
            var y = $(this).offset().top;

            var para = document.createElement("p");
            $("#annotations").append(para);
            para.innerHTML="this is an annotation";
            para.css("position",'absolute');
            para.style.top = y;
        });
    </script>
```

And here it is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yujuns/HDe6v/3/

Comment: Please try adding the CSS and best be if you could link to a codepen / jsfiddle so we can have a look at what you have done. You may continue me on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HDe6v/

Comment: Sure thank you i will do that. How do I import zurb foundation files in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that you want to change in your code.

First what you want is to get the offset of the selection. That can only happen if you put an html tag around the selection and then get its offset. You can then place an `absolute` positioned message box by setting its `left` and `top` offset to the offset you got from html element.

In the following fiddle, I have shown a basic implementation to give you the basic idea. Hope it helps.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/Yv46Y/)

**EDIT:**
Try this fiddle update.(In response to author's question). I have added comments to lines of code that I added to js. I also added `position: relative` to css for `annotations`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/HDe6v/4/)

Comment: Thank you! It looks good. But instead of using 'hide' and 'show' I want to create a new element each time when I highlight a sentence. So how to change the styles of the element lately created? I have updated my demo fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yujuns/HDe6v/3/

Comment: Note that if you click the text multiple times it will keep writing the message over previous message. You should check if there was a previous message and act accordingly.